# Web scraping: collect chart data

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, data-science, extract

I am completely new to web scraping, and I've decider to go for it, by learning some basis of Python.

The data I would like to collect is the chart on the following website :"https://www.amundi-ee.com/entr/product/view/QS0009102334" (no need for a login).

My main project is to create a small app to daily watch the curves and to add thresholds to advise me what to do.

Being a complete beginner in that domain, I would need some Help !

So far, I inspected the page and found the response that interests me ([Response containing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjMpA.png)

I already know how to get this response in python, but I don't know exactly how to extract these data objects from the response.

The code I've done so far :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

url = 'https://www.amundi-ee.com/entr/ezjscore/call/ezjscamundibuzz::sfForwardFront::paramsList=service=ProxyProductSheetFront&routeId=_FRA_fr-FR_849_QS0009102334_tab_2?standalone=true'

repsonse = urlopen(url).read()
print(response.text)
```

Thanks in advance !